# Free parameter in Bose Einstein Condensate

Tags: partition-function, bose-einstein-condensate, thermal-field-theory

In Kapusta and Gale's Finite-Temperature Field Theory book, BEC is derived for a complex scalar by Fourier expanding
$$\phi _1 = \sqrt2 \zeta \cos \theta + \sqrt{\frac{\beta}{V}}\sum_{n,\bar p}e^{i(\bar p \cdot\bar x + \omega _n \tau)}\phi_{1,n}(\bar p)$$
$$\phi _2 = \sqrt2 \zeta \sin \theta + \sqrt{\frac{\beta}{V}}\sum_{n,\bar p}e^{i(\bar p \cdot\bar x + \omega _n \tau)}\phi_{2,n}(\bar p)$$
then calculating the partition function to get
$$\ln Z = \beta V (\mu ^2 - m^2) \zeta^2 - V \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3}\left( \beta \omega + \ln(1-e^{-\beta(\omega - \mu )}) + \ln(1-e^{-\beta(\omega + \mu )}) \right) \,.$$
We note that $\theta$ is eliminated as expected by symmetry considerations, while for $\zeta$ we require for a fixed temperature and chemical that
$$\partial_\zeta \ln Z= 2\beta V (\mu^2 -m^2)\zeta = 0 \,,$$
and this is "where the magic happens", for when $|\mu| = m$ we will get some $\zeta>0$, i.e. a condensate.

My question is, why do we need to set $\partial _\zeta \ln Z = 0$? What is the physical meaning and justification for this condition?

Answer (score 0):

But your equation $\partial_\zeta \ln Z=0$ does not fix $\zeta$! Either $\zeta=0$, or, when  $\mu= m$, any value is allowed. This latter case  corresponds to any condensate density $\langle \phi\rangle^2= |\zeta|^2$ being possible.  Thus when we have a non-interacting bose gas with a condensate you will have $\mu$ exactly equal to $m$.  It is only when you have an interaction that there will be a non-trvial relation between $\mu$  and the condensate fraction $\zeta$ given by minimizing something like 
$$
V(\phi)= \frac 12 (m^2-\mu^2) |\phi|^2 +\frac 1{4!} (|\phi|^2)^2
$$
to find $\langle \phi\rangle=\zeta$.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't clear in the question, will edit post. I didn't mean to talk about what happens when $|\mu|  = m$, only the condition itself - why do we need $\partial_\zeta \ln Z = 0$ in the first place?

Comment: @Yoni becuase you are replacing the annihilation operator $\phi_0$ for, say, the $n=0$ by c-number (you are bit vague in your question but I assume that  you are doing quantum thermodynamics so  the $\phi_n$ are annihilation operators) and you need to determine it by some equation of motion.